# Testing cointegration in a VECM with autocorrelation?

Tags: regression, vector-autoregression, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

I have four I(1) (monthly) variables. AIC is used to determine the number of lags. A VECM is estimated by  ML-method and the Eigevalues imply that there are two cointegrating vectors. Now the problem is that the residuals of the VECM are autocorrelated. I tried to omit the autocorrelation by adding further dummies (seasonal dummies are already included) and more lags but both did not work.

Is it still reasonable to conclude that the variables are cointegrated? I read some threads claiming that the properties of the residuals are not important when analyzing cointegration as cointegration is a "deep" property of the data and does not depend on well-behaving residuals, but I am very unsure about this claim.